# getting columns from multiple tables into 1 datagridview in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I'm asking once more, since I'm really new in vb, I am using visual studio 2010 and mysql for my database, I need help getting different columns from different tables but same database and load it into one datagridview. Any kind of help or tips would be much appreciated . Please and Thank you.

Comment: Do you know how to join tables in sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use a `DataTable` with all joined columns as datasource which you can fill with a `DataAdapter`:

```
Private Function GetDataSource() As DataTable
    Const sqlSelect As String = "SELECT a.Col1 AS aCol1,a.Col2 AS aCol2,b.Col1 AS bCol1,b.Col2 AS bCol2 " & _
                               "FROM dbo.TableA AS a INNER JOIN dbo.TableB AS b ON a.IdCol=b.aIdCol " & _
                               "ORDER BY aCol1 ASC,bCol1 ASC"
    Try
        Dim table = New DataTable()
        Using con = New MySqlConnection(My.Settings.MySqlConnectionString)
            con.Open()
            Using da = New MySqlDataAdapter(sqlSelect, con)
                da.Fill(table)
                Return table
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' log message instead '
        Throw ' don't use throw new Exception or throw ex '
    End Try
End Function
```

Now you can use this `DataTable` as DataSource for the `DataGridView`:

```
me.dataGridView1.DataSource = GetDataSource()
```

Comment: Thank you for replying... I'm going to try using this now... I'll update you. Thanks again.

Comment: @TimSchemlter Please do bear with me I am just really new with vb and sql... what is this line for "ON a.IdCol=b.aIdCol"?

Comment: @user1746113: Sorry, i've overlooked the MySQL tag in the first place, edited the answer accordingly to take that into account. An inner [**join**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html) will only select records where the joined keys are in both specified tables. Since you haven't shown your data model, i have used exemplary columns. In this case `TableA` is the parent table and `TableB` the child table which references `TableA` in a foreign key column. So `TableB.aIdCol` is just an example for a column which references the primary key of `TableA`. The `ON` clause joines both table.

Comment: @TimSchemlter ohh thank you and sorry I forgot to place my data model as well.. I haven't got the hang of posting here. hmmm, I have 2 tables in my database forms, 1st table is formcreation and 2nd table is formtable. form creation has 4 columns ID(pk, AI), FormCode(double), FormName(varchar), HasSeries(text). and for formtable I (originally) had 4 columns aswell ID(PK, AI) I removed this because I thought there might be link problems (again Im sorry I don't know the exact term for that as I am really new with all this), Description(varchar), SeriesFrom(double), and SeriesTo(Double).

Comment: @TimSchemlter Thank you for your  answer with a little tweeks I managed to use it... :D I also found another way of doing it via drag drop :D http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/2be1532f-347d-482d-88c5-f6c06309851d/

Smoore16's answer